# Remove commas from right side of string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have string like below.

```
string s="this is item1,item2,item3,,, ,, ,";
```

now i want to remove (,) from right side of string.

Thanks in advance

i have tried

```
string.Replace(",", "");
```

and

```
string.TrimEnd("'");
```

but not working

Comment: single comma or all commas from the right side ? e.g., `this is item1,item2,item3`

Comment: You can try this regex: `([,\s*]+)$` to handle only last `,` remove `+` sign from pattern. http://rubular.com/r/EVASTuoQcF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
s = s.TrimEnd(',', ' ');
```

I think the problem in your code is that you do not assign the result of your replacement to any variable. And also your solution would remove all `,` from the string, not only those on the right side.

Comment: i think the replacement will add space ..which is not necessary ..  so i think it shud be ''.

Answer (score 3):

Try `string.TrimEnd():`

```
s= s.TrimEnd(',',' ');
```